# CSS Responsive Variables

Tags: html, css

I have a column with elements next to each other.

To create a gap between the elements, um using the `margin` property.

Now Im trying to add a responsive styling.

For a device with 320px width, im using margin: 3.20px

For a device with 420px width, im using margin: 4.20px

For a device with 520px width, im using margin: 5.20px

and so on...

Is there any way to apply these commands in a more elegant way?

Usually I would go with

```
@media all and (min-width: 320px) {
.Column {margin: 3.20px}

@media all and (min-width: 420px) {
.Column {margin: 4.20px !important}

@media all and (min-width: 520px) {
.Column {margin: 5.20px !important}

@media all and (min-width: 620px) {
.Column {margin: 6.20px !important}
```

and so on...

Is there any more elegant solution for this?

Comment: .Column {margin: 1%;}

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage css Variables (aka CustomProperties) to make it work.
css properties are widely supported now (except IE11, still you can have a polyfill to help you there).
Read more about cssVars: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

```css
/* demo */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* real code */

@media all and (min-width: 320px) {
  .column {
    margin: var(--column-margin, 3.20px);
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 420px) {
  .column {
    --column-margin: 4.20px;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 520px) {
  .column {
    --column-margin: 5.20px;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 620px) {
  .column {
    --column-margin: 6.20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
```